# How to validate email in all the possible ways in Flutter TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart, email, email-validation

I want to validate the email in all possible ways. I've checked many posts on Stackoverflow, and most of the answers suggest using **Regex**, but it does not validate domain names. For example,if I enter test@gmail.cofaa, it validates as the correct one. I also checked the *email_validator* package, which also did not give the solution. Is there any method to solve my problem?

I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

1. **email_validator: ^2.1.17**

   import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

   ```
    bool isValidEmail(String email) {
      if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
        return false;
      }

      if (!email.endsWith('@example.com')) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
   ```
2. **Regex.**

   bool isValidEmail(String email) {

   final emailRegex = RegExp(
   r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$',
   );

   if (!emailRegex.hasMatch(email)) {
   return false;
   }

   if (!email.endsWith('@example.com')) {
   return false;
   }

   return true;
   }

Comment: Bad regex.  Don't use that.  Rules out a perfectly valid email of <fred&barney@stonehenge.com> which for 20 years has been an auto-reply bot for exactly this occasion.

Comment: Should I customise the '@example.com' according to the domain names?